# Search by text and find all values in that row

Tags: excel, search, replace, vba

What I am trying to achieve is I want to search and retrieve data from an table. However, the problem is I do not know how to create a function that searches through a table and retreives an array from the search text.

Please, take a look at the picture and you will understand what I am trying to achieve. What I want is, when I for instance search "BMW", it searches through the table and retrieves those rows which has same vendors.

Any ideas how I can solve this problem? I have used VLOOKUP, but it retrieves one data. 
[image]

Comment: Why not just use the filter on the Car Vendors column shown in your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array formula, entered with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>, to get this.

Assuming your main data is in `A1:D6` (including header row), you can use this formula:

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$6,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$6=$G$2,ROW(A$2:A$6)-ROW(A$2)+1),ROWS(A$2:A2)))
```

Where `G2` is the cell with the Car you want to return the values for.  Enter the formula, and you can drag right:
[image]

Finally, just wrap `IfError([that formula],"")` around it, to put empty cells where there's not a match.

(Adjust your ranges as necessary).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple macro and link it to a button on the page. Change Criteria1 to whatever cell you are typing the Vendor into.

```
Sub dataFilter()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(*table name*).Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
    Criteria1:="B2", Operator:=xlFilterValues

end sub
```